# Problema de logout com php

Tags: php, mysql, html5, mysqli, login

Estou tentando fazer um sistema de login simples para aprender e aprimorá-lo, eu usei de base uma matéria que vi no devmedia, sendo que a matéria já era antiga, pois ainda usava mysql ao em vez de mysqli para conexão, nessa matéria não continha logout, depois de fazer o login, para deslogar somente limpando os cookies pelo navegador.

Estou tentando implementar um logout, mas não estou conseguindo, depois de entrar na página de logout aparece uma mensagem, porém quando é redirecionado para o index ainda aparece como se estivesse logado.

Já tentei várias coisas e nada funcionou, tentei inclusive setcookie, sendo que quando ia para a página de index, o login aparecia como um espaço em branco, mas não como null.

Estou colocando o código das páginas index.php, login.php e logout.php abaixo, além delas também tem as páginas de cadastro e a html de login, sendo que tenho quase certeza que o problema não é lá, pois o cadastro está salvando corretamente no banco, e duvido muito disso ser um erro em html. Deixei o logout dessa forma pois foi o que eu mais vi em minhas pesquisas.

index.php:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

    $login_cookie = $_COOKIE['login'];

    if(isset($login_cookie) === true)
    {
        echo"Bem-Vindo, $login_cookie <br>";
        echo"Essas informações <font color='red'>PODEM</font> ser acessadas por você";
        echo"<br><a href='logout.php'>Sair</a>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo"Bem-Vindo, convidado <br>";
        echo"Essas informações <font color='red'>NÃO PODEM</font> ser acessadas por você";
        echo"<br><a href='login.html'>Faça Login</a> Para ler o conteúdo";
    }
?>
```

login.php:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

    $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','logindevmedia') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');

    if (isset($_POST['login']) === true) 
    {
        $login = $_POST['login'];
    } 
    else 
    {
        $login = false;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['senha']) === true) 
    {
        $senha = MD5($_POST['senha']);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $senha = false;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['entrar']) === true) 
    {
        $entrar = $_POST['entrar'];
    } 
    else 
    {
        $entrar = false;
    }

    if (isset($entrar)) 
    {
        $query_select = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$login' AND senha = '$senha'";

        $verifica = mysqli_query($connect,$query_select) or die("erro ao selecionar");

        if (mysqli_num_rows($verifica)<=0)
        {
            echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Login e/ou senha incorretos');window.location.href='login.html';</script>";
            die();
        }
        else
        {
            setcookie("login",$login);
            header("Location:index.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

    session_start();

    session_unset();   // remove all session variables

    session_destroy();  // destroy the session

    echo "<script>alert('Você saiu!'); document.location.href='index.php';</script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está utilizando cookie para fazer o login do usuário, no entanto na hora de fazer o logout você está limpando as variáveis de sessão, por isso que não funciona. Você deve fazer a remoção do cookie.

Comment: Sim, eu estou tentando remover o cookie mas não estou conseguindo, já tentei usar unset($_COOKIE['login']); session_unset($_COOKIE['login']);  setcookie('login'); mas nada funciona.

Comment: Faça `setcookie("login","",time()-3600)`

Comment: se  todas as páginas estiverem no mesmo diretório `setcookie("login","",time()-3600)` vai funcionar

Comment: Funcionou, mas ficou uma dúvida, eu devo deixar o meu logout como está, ou devo remover os sessions e deixar apenas o setcookie? Eu testei somente com setcookie("login","",time()-3600) e ele já desloga.

Comment: Aparentemente sua aplicação não usa Sessions em momento algum, então você pode remover esse trecho de código. Caso use, você deve deixar.